# Unable to assign QQmlListReference to QString

Tags: javascript, qml, qt-creator

So I had a fun problem with list models and delegates.

```
ListView{
....
    delegate: Component {
        Text{
            text: data
        }
    }
}
...

ListModel {
    id: captureModel
}

...

function updateList() {
    ...
    for (var i = 0; i < list.rows.length; ++i) {
        captureModel.append({"data": list.rows.item(i).data});
    }
}
```

When I tried to append new elemets to the list model I got this error: "Unable to assign QQmlListReference to QString." I finally figured out that the problem was that my list element was called data. I just named it something else and it worked just fine. I thought the problem was that "data" was a reserved word, but I couldn't find it in either Javascript or QML lists. Though I couldn't find an official qml reserved word list. So do you guys know of a more complete list? I will like to avoid finding reserved words like this again or if the issue is actually something else I will like to hear the answer for that.

These are the lists that I was looking at:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp (Javascript).

https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/commit/?id=4cc61d0449ed463408633016759694bc59badc04 (qml)

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that your problem is because your list element role is called `data`.

The underlying problem is that when you do `text: data` you are accessing the [`data` property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#data-prop) of your Text item. Your model data is shadowed by the property.

To be on the safe side, prefix your access to your roles with `model` to avoid a naming clash with your delegate properties. In your case it will be `text: model.data`.

`data` is not a reserved keyword, it just happens to be the name of one of your delegate's properties.